# Android fragment toolbar home button not working properly | Android studio

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar

If I am in some fragment(not home fragment) if I click home button (toolbar),then current fragment is replaced with home fragment(It is working correctly).

Now problem is, (after pressing home button)  if I press back button **entire app stops working or sometime two fragment contents are overlapped**

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/botton_navigation"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_area"                                  (*) focus here
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


            </FrameLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/botton_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"

        app:itemBackground="@color/college_color_dark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.class

```
homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
                                   (*) this part should executes
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_area, homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

same class below.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

if(item.getItemId()==R.id.home){ //home button in toolbar
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_area, homeFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();



        }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am getting wrong ?

Comment: What does "the entire app stop working" mean? If it crashes, include the full stack trace. What other FragmentTransactions are you doing? Do they use `addToBackStack()`?

Comment: ```case 0:
    newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
                                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_area, newsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                ;```

every fragment I am doing this